# NoMethod Error with on a `favorites' join model Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to allow a `User` to favorite a `coffee_roast`. However on trying to load the show page I get a NoMethod Error

> undefined method `favorite_coffee_roast_path'

which comes from this line of code:

```
  <%= link_to "Add to favorites", favorite_coffee_roast_path(@coffee_roast, type: "favorite"), method: :put %><br />
```

I have tried a number of variations such as:

- `favorite_roast_coffee_roast_path`
- `favorite_coffeeroast_coffee_roast_path`
- `favorite_coffee_roast_coffee_roast_path`

None obviously work.

**My Models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_merit
  has_one :drink
  has_many :coffeeshops
  has_many :coffee_roasts
  has_many :favorite_coffeeroasts
  has_many :favorite_roasts, through: :favorite_coffeeroasts, source: :coffee_roast

class CoffeeRoast < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :favorite_coffeeroasts
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_coffeeroasts, source: :user

class FavouriteCoffeeroast < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :coffee_roast
    belongs_to :user
```

**My Controller**

```
class CoffeeRoastsController < ApplicationController
...
  def favorite_coffeeroast
    @coffee_roast = CoffeeRoast.find(params[:id])
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
    current_user.favorite_roasts << @coffee_roast
    redirect_to @coffee_roast, notice: "You favorited #{@coffee_roast.name}"

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorite_roasts.delete(@coffee_roast)
      redirect_to @coffee_roast, notice: "Unfavorited #{@coffee_roast.name}"

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to @coffee_roast, notice: "Nothing happened."
      end
    end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  #core root
  get 'home/index' => 'home#index'
  root 'home#index'

  #roasts redirect
  get '/roasts', to: redirect('/coffee_roasts', status: 302)

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :roasts
    end
  end
  resources :blends
  resources :roasters
  resources :countries
  resources :regions
  resources :comments
  resources :coffee_flavours
  resources :flavours
  resources :drinks
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :admins
  resources :varietals
  resources :tags
  resources :coffee_beans
  resources :coffee_roasts
  resources :processings


  get 'contact-me', to: 'messages#new', as: 'new_message'
  post 'contact-me', to: 'messages#create', as: 'create_message'


#static pages
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
get 'cookiepolicy', to: 'pages#cookiepolicy'
get 'map', to: 'pages#map'
get 'longblack', to: 'longblack#index'
get 'prices', to: 'prices#new'
post 'prices', to: 'prices#create'


#db resources
resources :roasters do
   resources :comments
end
resources :articles do
   resources :comments
end
resources :coffeeshops do
  resources :comments
end
resources :roasts do
  resources :comments
end
resources :coffee_roasts do
  resources :comments
end
resources :coffeeshops do
  put :favorite, on: :member
end

resources :coffeeshops do
  put :bookmarked, on: :member
end
```

Why can't I find the right path? What am I missing?

Comment: may i know your config/routes.rb

Comment: just added routes

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add `favorite_coffeeroast` action to routes file :) After it you can find the correct path name with `rake routes | grep favorite` command in the terminal

Comment: thanks @Vasilisa I've added `resource :favorite_coffeeroast` and the page now loads, however when trying to 'favorite` I get `uninitialized constant FavoriteCoffeeroastController`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to read more about [routing in ROR](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Add the new action to existing `resources :coffee_roasts`:

```
resources :coffee_roasts do
  put :favorite_coffeeroast, on: :member
  resources :comments
end
```

Also you are duplicating routes when you write them with and without nesting. Since you want to nest everywhere comments routes you can remove corresponding routes without nesting

Comment: The thing is, I have this working with another model `coffeeshops` perfectly.  I've not needed to update the routes as such. I'm just trying to replicate what I have done there, but this path issue has been preventing me. For instance, in your snippet above you have `on: :member` but i have removed the member model. Yes I need to clean up my routes file.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand you. You don't want to create a new route for the controller action but you want it to work? `on: :member` just tells you, how route should like, should it have :id segment or not